# How to use the graph API to upload photos to albums

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

My code(not working):

```
<?php
require '../src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '...',
  'secret' => '...'
));

Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false; 
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

if ($user) {
  $album_id = '246592692052269';    
  $FILE_PATH = 'Language.jpg';
  $access_token = $_SESSION['fb_appId_access_token'];
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
   $args = array('image'=> '@' . __DIR__.$FILE_PATH, 
           'name' => 'this photo was taken in acre',
          'message'=> 'Photo Caption'); 
    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/'.$album_id.'/photos?access_token='.$access_token;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    //returns the photo id
    if(empty($data)) {
    echo 'Responde: '. $data . '<pre>';
    print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
    echo '</pre>';
    } else {
    echo 'Upload failed! erro='. curl_error($ch);
    }

} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://graph.facebook.com/246592692052269/photos?access_token=...
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.203
    [namelookup_time] => 0
    [connect_time] => 0.203
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.203
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
)
```

Can someone point out my error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure file uploads are enabled on the server side, and initialize the SDK with `fileUpload` set to `true` as described on the [PHP SDK documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) page, or call [`setFileUploadSupport`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-setFileUploadSupport/). You don't need to manually call the graph API with the access token and `curl` commands as you are doing above, the PHP SDK will take care of that for you. See the [`api` method documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/) page for a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

Check out facebook's howto: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/